# How do I return yes or no from a message box that I made?

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a message box, a form that has a label for a message and a label for the title.

And an OK button (do nothing).

I can rise this message box from any form in my program.

I need a message box that has a <kbd>Yes</kbd> button and <kbd>No</kbd> button, and to know if it pressed <kbd>Yes</kbd> or <kbd>No</kbd>, how do I do it?

What would sample code for this be?

Comment: just make the Main method in your custom messagebox return a DialogResult instead of void

Answer (score 16):

From [MSDN MessageBox.Show(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z.aspx):

```
// Initializes the variables to pass to the MessageBox.Show method.

string message = "You did not enter a server name. Cancel this operation?";
string caption = "Error Detected in Input";
MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
DialogResult result;

// Displays the MessageBox.

result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);

if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // Closes the parent form.
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Exactly my thought; why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Um, because the regular message box cannot be moved to the center of the app where it belongs. It is always aligned with the center of the screen.

Answer (score 6):

In your button's click event handler use

```
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes;
```

instead of

```
this.Close();
```

And then handle it as normal in your calling code.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
dialogResult dr;
dr = MessageBox.show("Do you want to save the record", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dr == DialogResult.yes)
{
    //Code for inserting the data into the database
    messageBox.show("Record saved successfully");
}
```

This code is for if you want to save the form data to the database after confirmation. Here I only show how to access the value of a message box where the user presses which button.

Comment: Please give more information in your answer and not just the code

Answer (score 1):

`MessageBox.Show` has the following method signature:

```
public static DialogResult Show(
    string text,
    string caption,
    MessageBoxButtons buttons
)
```

Which means you can specify what buttons you would like to display.

#### Example

```
var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you have socks?", "Question.", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

These are the following MessageBoxButtons you can select from:

- OK
- OKCancel
- AbortRetryIgnore
- YesNoCancel
- YesNo
- RetryCancel

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return different kinds of results (like, say, a string of text) you can do something like this:

```
public class MyMessageBox : Form
{
    // You can add parameters here if needed
    public static string Ask()
    {
        var form = new MyMessageBox();
        form.ShowDialog();
        return form.ResponseTextBox.Text;
    }
    // regular stuff
}
```

Then just do

```
string answer = MyMessageBox.Ask();
```

If running on Windows Vista or later, you can use the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) to use the new [TaskDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760441.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function to do this:

```
var result = MessageBox.Show("your message here", "title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (result == DialogResult.Yes) {
    // .. 
}
```

If you want to do similar, but with your own custom form, just set the "Yes" button's `DialogResult` to `Yes` and the "No" button's to `No`, and then call `ShowDialog()` on your form.